# How can I get values from decoded file

Tags: json

I have a JSON file. When I encoded and decoded it, it gives me a resultset like below:

```
{
  "_id": 519188,
  "name": "Novinki",
  "country": "RU",
  "coord": {
    "lon": 37.666668,
    "lat": 55.683334
  }
}
```

How can I get the values from that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with javascript, you need to store the contents of json file into a javascript variable. From there you can easily access the values.

```
eg:- var someVariable = decodedFileContent;
         var id = someVariable._id;
```

Hope it helps.Give more information.

Comment: not in JS format, in json format and try to get it in PHP

Comment: Then you need some kind of json parser.I know how to do it in java.You need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java for PHP. Hope this helps.